# Prove or disprove: the series $\sum\frac{1}{nb_n\log n}$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to determine whether the following statement is true or false:
Let $b_n$ be an unbounded non decreasing sequence such that for every $\epsilon > 0$, $\lim \frac{b_n}{\log^\epsilon n} = 0$.

Then the series $\sum\frac{1}{nb_n\log n}$ diverges.

How can I prove or disprove the above statement?

Any attempts to use the comparison test leads to an inconclusive result.

Any hints will be very appreciated.

Comment: What about $b_n = \log^2(\log(n))$ ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I will try

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Did you know in advance that series converges? Its not so trivial to prove the convergence of that series.

Comment: It is not so trivial indeed, but it is a good exercise ! (and yes, it converges)

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Ok, Thanks. Any of the standard theorems should work here?

Comment: Yes, you can apply [Cauchy's condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TheSilderDoe mentioned, you can consider the sequence $b_n=\log^2(\log n).$ It satisfies $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n/\log^\epsilon(n)=0$ for any $\epsilon>0$. If you apply the Cauchy Condensation twice test to the sequence $\frac{1}{n\log^2(\log n)\log n}$, you find that the convergence of its series is equivalent to the convergence of $\sum_{n\ge 1}1/n^2$, which of course converges